# Chrome + LCD Font Smoothing = Not Working

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Recently, LCD font smoothing stopped working on Chrome; it happened no more than two weeks ago. Seeing that I use Chrome as my default browser, this issue is very annoying, as I prefer the look of "smooth" font.

Do you have any idea what would be causing this? I've tested it in Safari, and the text looks perfect.

I'm running the follow version: 18.0.1025.142
Comparison:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text renders awfully in Chrome on a PC, yet fine in all other modern web browsers](http://superuser.com/questions/367776/text-renders-awfully-in-chrome-on-a-pc-yet-fine-in-all-other-modern-web-browser)

Comment: It might be better to use an example image that doesn't promote a commercial product - just a thought!

Comment: I like it better without the smoothing, it that just me?

Comment: @brad-fiedel How about now? Still have the problem?

Comment: @emb1995 I originally posted this on MacRumors, and I'm still having this problem.